# Parent window details are not getting updated from child window in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

I am using google maps API in my application. I am opening the child window from parent window. After this from child window (This window contains map) user will select the area by left clicking on the map. At this event I am updating "longitude" and "latitude" from child window to parent window hidden field. This is working fine in IE and Mozilla but not working in Google chrome.

Here is the code (Client window JavaScript):

```
function placeMarker(location) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: location, map: map, animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP});
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitude: ' + location.lng()});
    infowindow.open(map,marker);

    window.opener.document.getElementById("longitude").value=location.lat();
    window.opener.document.getElementById("latitude").value=location.lng();

}
```

Parent window hidden field code:

```
<input id="longitude" type="hidden" name="longitude" value=""/>
<input id="latitude" type="hidden" name="latitude" value=""/>
```

From parent window opening child window code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="popupwindow('googleMaps.html?longitude='+document.getElementById('longitude').value+'&latitude='+document.getElementById('latitude').value+'&areaName='+document.getElementById('sublocality_level_1').value+'&subAreaName='+document.getElementById('sublocality_level_2').value, 'Google maps', 915, 545);" class="btn">Locate your house on the Google maps</button>
```

Java Script to open windiw:

```
function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {

        if ((document.getElementById('longitude').value == '') && (document.getElementById('latitude').value == '')) {

            alert('Please select proper area name.');
            return false;

        }   
        var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
        var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
        return window.open(url, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to access parent window through 'parent' variable. It should work in Chrome.

```
parent.window.opener.document.getElementById("longitude").value=location.lat();
parent.window.opener.document.getElementById("latitude").value=location.lng();
```

Comment: No still the same problem even after adding parent.

Comment: I found the problem. In normal prototype HTML its not working. When i deploy this code into server like Apache Tomcat then its working fine. But not able to find the reason if its normal page then why its not able to update the parent window.